# Understanding Google Search Console URL Testing Tools API Limits

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer, google-developers-console, google-search-console

I am using Google Search Console URL Testing Tools API, I have a problem in the understanding limit quota of API. It says:

**Project per-second limit per 100 seconds  = 1**

**User per-second limit per 100 seconds per user     = 1**

[image: Have a look here]

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Most of highly used APIs (google, facebook..) have short-time limits and long-time limits for better control over traffic. It allows developers make many requests (eg. 20000 per day) but prevents throttling if someone would try to eg. send 1000 requests in one second, which could clog api endpoint.

What you have in your google console:

> Project per-second limit per 100 seconds = 1

That means you can make 1 query for 100 seconds in each project.

And:

> User per-second limit per 100 seconds per user = 1

That means you can make 1 query for 100 seconds for each user connected to project.

That two limit rules putted together dont make much sense beacuse second rule will never be triggered (both have 1 request per 100 seconds but first one is for 'higher' resource and will block more requests).

Example of many limits you can see eg. in Analytics API where we have:

> Queries per day = 50000

Big limit for queries per day.

> Queries per 100 seconds per user = 100

Small limit per 100 seconds and per user so they can prevent too high peaks of requests from single user.

> Queries per 100 seconds = 2000

Medium limit per 100 seconds.